# What are the best practices in Allure TestOps?

Tags: regression-testing, allure

We use Allure TestOps as a system where we track regression testing progress/launches, we have 7 projects (one for each team) in this system. Every regression we create launches for different mobile platforms and in the end there are a bunch of regression testing reports.

We have two options, to have them still separate and have a lot of reports at once or to mix them in one and to share only one regression report from all teams.

The decision to mix them appeared because our QA manager wants to track everything himself, to create launches and test plans himself (before we did it on our own in each team). The problem that he wanted to address is to make the process clearer to him and to make it easier for him to control it all.

What could be the pros and cons for both of them in your opinion, and how it works in your company?

Does it make any sense to mix them in one and then filter the test cases by projects anyway?

Or will it be better to have them separate?

Comment: To clarify, are those 7 projects all different from one another? Or, are there commonalities between them? Like, is 1 the main project and 6 are sub-features of the project?

Comment: Actually all the projects are working on different functionality in the app